# Formatting rows in excel using sheetjs in angular2

Tags: excel, angular, typescript, exceljs

I am using [Sheetjs](https://github.com/protobi/js-xlsx) to write json content in the file. I am able to write into file and download. Most my report export intigrated with this an everything works.
But I have recently got new excel format which looks something like 
[image]
I am not able to implement like this using sheetjs. I tried most of issue on GIT account and read about it ,but still nothing helped me.
Below is the  generic code block for reference

```
public exportAsExcelFile(jsonint: any[], excelFileName: string,replaceMap:any,headerOrder: string[]): boolean {

var jsonData =this.replaceKeyInObjectArray(jsonint,replaceMap);
var orderedJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( jsonData, headerOrder, 10));



let worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(orderedJSON);

const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: {'data': worksheet}, SheetNames: ['data'] };

const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook,{ bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });

this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
return true; }



 private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
    const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
      type: EXCEL_TYPE
    })

FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '-' + Util.getCurrDate("_") + EXCEL_EXTENSION);  }
```

If someone know this help me out.Thanks in advance

Comment: If Sheetjs is also called js-xlsx then you should tag your question also with the `js-xlsx` tag